# Python Extract a decimal number before a specific substring

Tags: python, regex, string, list-comprehension

I want to extract a number before a specific substring ("per cent")

I tried to used the split function

```
str1="The percentage of success for Team A is around 7.5 per cent. What about their season ?"
print(str1.split("per cent",1)[0])
```

Expected result: `"7.5"`

Actual result: `"The percentage of success for Team A is around 7.5"`

Comment: `"The percentage of success for Team A is around 7.5".rsplit()[-1]`

Comment: @Matthias I have multiple strings to work with and they don't have the same beginning "The percentage of success for Team A is around 7.5". And I want to extract the per cent value of all these strings

Comment: And where is the problem? You can first apply the `split` you did and then in a second step the next one.

Comment: @aelayath u can do `[i[-1] for i in st1.split('per cent')]`

Comment: @aelayath let me know if my answer helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I will cover 4 cases: A) only positive decimals expressed using `.`, B) ANY decimals expressed using `.`, C) MULTIPLE decimals expressed using `.`, D) MULTIPLE decimals expressed using `.` OR `,`.**

A) Assuming that **your float is always expressed in decimal notation**

```
import re

results = re.findall("\d+\.\d+",str1)[0]
print(results)
#'7.5'
```

B) **If you also have *NEGATIVE* decimals use this (more robust):**

```
results = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+",str1)
```

C) **If you have MULTIPLE decimals use this:**

```
str1="The percentage of success for Team A is around 7.5 per cent and 2.3"

results = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+",str1)

len(results)
#2 since it found the 2 decimals.

# Use list comprehension to store the detected decimals.
final_results = [i for i in results]
print(final_results)
#['7.5', '2.3']
```

D) **Finally, if the decimals are expressed either using `.` (dot) or `,`(comma) then use the super robust:**

```
str1="The percentage of success for Team A is around 7.5 per cent and 2,3"

results = re.findall(r"\d+[.,]*\d*[.,]*\d*",str1)
final_results = [i for i in results]
#['7.5', '2,3']
```

Comment: Your answer is working. If I have multiple numbers in one string, How can I extract all of them ?

Comment: This is my main REGEX to extract prices from text, we can merge both to make a stronger regex "\d+[.,]*\d*[.,]*\d*" (sometime they use dot or comma)

Comment: @Wonka that's true. The OP did not address this but I have integrated it into my answer. Cheers

Comment: thank you for your help ! Do you have any idea to include number like this : 1,075.01 ? PLease

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/string-methods.html) to find the index where `per cent` takes place, slice the string up to the resulting index, then `rstrip` and `split` keeping the last element from the resulting list:

```
str1[:str1.index('per cent')].rstrip().split()[-1]
# '7.5'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex for this:

```
import re

str1="The percentage of success for Team A is around 7.5 per cent. What about their season ?"

m = re.search('([0-9.-]+) per cent', str1)
m[1]
=>7.5
```

What I did is the following: I created a regex that matches any combination of digits, dash and dot (to crudely match a number that is possibly negative) followed by the exact text `per cent`.

I specified the number as a group and so you can get it by accessing the 1-th index of the found match.

Answer (score 0):

```
str1.split('per cent')[0].split(' ')[-2]
```